# App crashes after renaming it

Tags: android

I renamed my Project in eclipse I tried to run my app on my device. but ever since  I am getting Unfortunately, App has stopped. I manually edited the AndroidManifest.xml to check if the file paths are correct as AndroidManifest doesn't seem to reflect the changes after renaming project, I would be grateful if you help. Here is the logcat

`02-09 11:38:43.872: D/AndroidRuntime(26838): Shutting down VM
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838): Process: com.ummahtalk.community, PID: 26838
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ummahtalk.community-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4491)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ummahtalk.community-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:979)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    ... 10 more
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):        ... 13 more
02-09 11:38:43.880: E/AndroidRuntime(26838):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
02-09 11:38:53.991: D/AndroidRuntime(27142): Shutting down VM
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142): Process: com.ummahtalk.community, PID: 27142
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ummahtalk.community-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4491)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ummahtalk.community-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:979)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    ... 10 more
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ummahtalk.community.SpikaApp
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):        ... 13 more
02-09 11:38:53.993: E/AndroidRuntime(27142):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
02-09 11:39:54.371: I/Process(27142): Sending signal. PID: 27142 SIG: 9`

Comment: This is a simple error , my suggestion would be do some Google before posting a question. However your application must have an activity named  'SpikaApp' and it must be inside package "com.ummahtalk.community" and same should be enlisted in your manifest.

Comment: Sorry, but I am very new to Android

Answer (score 0):

I had renamed the project using Android Tools>>Rename Application package but Then I figured out everything was not renamed correctly then I tried doing Refactor>Rename and It solved it

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the exact problem. I tried all the solutions above non worked. 
I got it fixed by exiting android studio, copying the entire project folder to a new location, launching android studio and opening the project from the new location.